# Why does not RestSharp support synchronous requests on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

Why does not RestSharp support synchronous requests on Windows Phone? I am curious, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

All network-related Windows Phone (and Windows Store app) IO is asynchronous. The idea is that you should embrace asynchrony, in order to keep your UI responsive.

Have a look at the "core" APIs around `WebRequest` etc - all the synchronous parts are deliberately missing in the Windows Phone version.

It would be odd for RestSharp to buck the trend here.